# Реально связать разные домены wordpress под одной админкой?

Tags: wordpress

Что бы была одна админке была на 3 сайта. Можно внутри неё переключатся между доменами. На каждом домене будет свой контент

Comment: Это точно реально. вот даю 100% что это реально, но сомневаюсь 1) что вам это нужно. 2) что вам это по силам.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков не надо ёрничать. Вам по силам - дайте человеку вменяемый ответ.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, человек задал вопрос, реально это или нет, на его вопрос я ответил, ибо на 100% уверен что можно "переписать" админку под его "пожелания", но простите переписывать ее у меня желания ровно ноль. а о том что это есть "из коробки" в какой либо версии мне не ведомо.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков это не ответ, а пустой комментарий, из которого видно, что 1) вам это не по силам, 2) знаний о предмете у вас нет. Раз у вас нет знаний о WordPress, то не стоит делать выводы о том, что нужно или не нужно людям. Multisite - широко известный, очень распространённый и востребованный режим работы WP.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Давайте вы не будете голословно решать что мне по силам а что нет, и обратите внимание где именно размещен мой "не ответ" =) в комментарии а не в виде ответа.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Если вы не знаете вордпресс -- лучше не пытаться отвечать, даже в комментах, ибо можно отвечать в основном правильно но иногда можно пролететь мимо, вот как сейчас. У KAGG уже почти золото по метке wordrpress, он знает о чём пишет. В вордпресс действительно есть multisite и настроить его может практически любая кухарка. Я настраивал как-то из любопытства - ничего сложного. И не стоит сильно оскорбляться - ну не знали, ну с кем не бывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен [WordPress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8).

Answer (score 1):

> Что бы была одна админке была на 3 сайта.

Именно так - не возможно по определению. Админка - это интерфейс управления конкретным сайтом. А вот переключаться между админками - не проблема.

Для этого или использовать [режим сети](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8) или плагины типа https://wordpress.org/plugins/mainwp/

*Хотя в чём сложность заходить в админки сайтов лично мне не понятно.*